# jQuery Post Callback from REST API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, rest, post

I am working on an app that will submit data to a REST API and have some questions.

1. How does jQuery know if my post request was successful or not?  Is it only looking at the HTTP status?
2. Is there a convention on what to return from a POST request to a REST API?

**JavaScript**

```js
$.post( '/API/removeUser', { Eid: id }, function(data) { row.remove(); } );
```

**PHP SLIM Framework**

```html
$app->POST('/API/removeUser', function () use ($app) {
    
    // Get the ID from the jQuery post         
    $Eid = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Eid'])));   
    
 echo json_encode(removeFunction($Eid));
 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your backend should always return the appropriate [HTTP status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) along with the actual data. 404 for resources that were not found, 403 for unauthorized requests, 200 for successful requests etc. Most AJAX libraries (including jQuery) will rely on those for determining the result of the operation.

If you need more fine-grained error reporting, you could always include a field like "errorCode" in your response that contains an application-level error code that you define yourself and react to accordingly in your frontend code.